# Make unique number from 2 numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is any simple method to find a unique number from 2 different ones?
Currently I'm using $xy+x-y$ eg: `6•8+6-8 = 46` but I'm not able to test its reliability

X and Y range is 1~999,999,999

Info: the result must be unique, the method will be used in a SQL Query, keeping it simple/basic would be perfect

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean with "make unique number". Do you want the result be unique or should the two numbers $x,y$ be unique given the result ?

Comment: @Peter the result should be unique

Comment: For positive integers $x$ and $y$, if their order is not important: $p_x \cdot p_y$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number.

Comment: @Peter I am a programmer not a Math man but from what I can understand my method can do the work without duplicate problems?

Comment: Or if you have a restricted range for $x$ and $y$, then it's even simpler.

Comment: Perhaps, I still misunderstand the question. If we have $x+y$, then $1+5$ and $2+4$ gives the same sum. So, would this be forbidden ?

Comment: @Peter exactly, it's forbidden

Comment: @barakmanos from 0 to 999,999,999

Comment: Then you can use $10000000000x+y$.

Comment: Use $10^{20}x+y$ with $0\le y<10^{20}$. Then, $x$ and $y$ are uniquely detemined by the result. Even $10^9$ is sufficient, as barak manos said.

Comment: @barakmanos right!! The simplest solution, can you answer with this?

Comment: @Peter would $10^{20}x+100y$ remove the $0\le y<10^{20}$. Limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to find a collision:
$$xy+x-y = (x-1)(y+1) + 1$$
so all we need is to find some number that can be written as a product in more than one way, and then declare the two factors to be $x-1$ or $y+1$, respectively.

For example $12=3\cdot 4=4\cdot 3$, so your function produces $13$ both for inputs $(4,3)$ and $(5,2)$.

---

What you want is a [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), for which many choices exist. A fairly practical one that works for nonnegative integers, as suggested by Wikipedia, is
$$ (x,y) \mapsto \frac{(x+y+1)(x+y)}2+x $$
For theoretical purposes it is sometimes convenient to use more "wasteful" functions such as 
$$ (x,y)\mapsto 2^x3^y $$
or
$$ (x,y) \mapsto 2^x(2y+1) $$

Comment: @HAlexTM: Your function maps $(3,4)$ to $11$, but $(4,3)$ maps to $13$.

Comment: that's why I tried to delete my comment Ahah

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y\in[0,999999999]$, then you can use $f(x,y)=1000000000x+y$.

Answer (score 0):

To see if your method works it is enough to see if

$$x\cdot y + x - y = x $$

or

$$x\cdot y + x - y = y $$

for any $x, y $.

Solving the first we get

$$ x\cdot y + x - y = x \iff x \cdot y - y = 0 \iff y(x-1) = 0 \iff x = 1 \vee y = 0$$

So your equation returns $x$ (regradless of $y $) if $x = 1$ or if $y = 0$ (regardless of $x $).

$$x\cdot y + x - y = y \iff x \cdot y + x = 2y \iff (y + 1)x = 2y \stackrel{y \not= -1}{\iff} x = \frac {2y}{y + 1}$$

Hence if $y \not= -1 \wedge x = \frac {2y}{y + 1}$ your method returns $y $.

Therefore your method is not 100% perfect. If you change it to

$$x\cdot y + x + y $$

By symmetry it would be enough to check that neither number is 0 or 1 to ensure it works.

Answer (score 0):

Pick two primes $p$ and $q$ larger than $999,999,999$.  Solve the system $t \equiv X \pmod{p}$, $t\equiv Y \pmod{q}$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Then $t$ will be unique for each pair $(X,Y)$ modulo $pq>10^{18}.$

Comment: bit complicated, don't you think

Comment: Yep.  But more fun than writing $X10^9+Y.$  Plato would agree with me.

Comment: True. Alternative solutions are always useful too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Equivalent Problem

To expand on the other answers posted, if you want to find a unique number for each $(x,y)$ pair of integers, you're really looking for a one-to-one function $f$, between $(x,y)$ and the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. In other words, an injection $f:\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$. Graphically, we can show $f$ in the diagram below as mapping between the grid of green points and the set of blue points, with the stipulation that no two blue points can have the same height.

[image]

It's quite simple to accommodate for the additional criterion that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ as we can choose the values of $f$ on one side of the plane $x=y$ and then allow $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ on the other side of the plane.

---

#### Solutions

1. One simple solution is to set all $(x,y)$ pairs into a grid with $x$ increasing along rows and $y$ increasing down columns. We then run a criss-crossing line through these points and take $f(x,y)$ as the position of $(x,y)$ along this line. This would look somewhat like the diagram below, which has fractions instead of number pairs.

[image]

2. As **Henning Makholm** points out, this is actually one of a larger family of functions called [Pairing Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), which have the neat additional property that *all* the numbers in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ can be mapped to. One such function is the one described in (1), the Cantor pairing function, $f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+x$. This particular function works because $\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}2$ is constant along each diagonal in the grid above. So $f$ increases linearly along each diagonal, as in the diagram below.

[image]

3. We can also use other functions such as $f(x,y)=(n+1)x+y$, if $x,y\leq n$ but this will only work if $x,y$ are strictly within these bounds. If you change the bounds later, this function might stop working, even though it seems neat at first.